# CTM seam line distortion

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

I have a model in Blender & as an .OBJ which looks fine & works perfectly with a UV map texture.

When converted to a CTM distorted seam lines appear on the model. This essentially makes the texture break like this, whereas on the OBJ it would have remained smooth –
 [image: CTM Render]

Looking around I found this suggested solution online, using the ‘Seams from Islands’ option. Seemed like the same issue, so I gave it a go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690459/strange-lines-seams-appearing-when-applying-texture-to-threejs-model 
But the model didn’t take it very well, making the issue worse.

[image: Seams from Islands tried]

Any suggestions on a fix we can implement in Blender for this CTM render would be highly appreciated. Thanks.